# Recursive SUM Sql Server parent-child-hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

Let's say we have the following table "#res"

```
    MatID                           Number  MatName StoreName                StoreID                        SParentID                           Qty
2CA241F6-F48C-4A37-B675-25134C7F84D4    1   Mat1    Store1          194AB76D-01AB-4351-BA6F-5BE0974628F7  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  12
2CA241F6-F48C-4A37-B675-25134C7F84D4    1   Mat1    Store2          3A34B4D1-5464-461A-9115-20446253FE99  194AB76D-01AB-4351-BA6F-5BE0974628F7  1
2CA241F6-F48C-4A37-B675-25134C7F84D4    1   Mat1    Store3          4594C677-3F55-4E27-8EC9-8209C86FC0CD  3A34B4D1-5464-461A-9115-20446253FE99  1
```

the table contain one mat "Mat1" in 3 different stores 1, 2, 3  as shown in SParentID Column "Store Parent " the store3 is child of parent store2 and store2 is has parent store1 (hierarchy):

```
   Store1
     |
   Store2
     |
   Store3
```

I want to add the value of qty in store3 to store2 to become 2, then add the 2 to the parent. Please note that this is  an example and i want to do it in general way regardless to number of children and the top parent may have parent that not exist in the record set!

Comment: This article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818694/SQL-queries-to-manage-hierarchical-or-parent-child) might help you. A more efficient way is changing your table to a nested set structure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). This allows you to get your desired result with one single query,

Comment: i prefer it to be in code rather than to do it in sql , any way thanks for the great article . all regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this recursive SELECT query. I renamed the main table as store. You can refer to [SQL recursive query structure using CTE](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx) at this referenced link

```
;with rcte as (
    select StoreId, SParentId, MatID, ISNULL(Qty,0) Qty from store where SParentId in (select StoreId from store)
    union all
    select 
        store.StoreId, store.SParentId, store.MatID, ISNULL(store.Qty,0) + rcte.Qty as Qty
    from store 
    inner join rcte
        on rcte.SParentId = store.StoreId
)
select
    *
from (
    select rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By StoreId Order By Qty Desc), * from rcte
) t
inner join store s ON s.MatID = t.MatID and s.StoreId = t.StoreId
where t.rn = 1
```

I hope it works